# Enlaces html pegados, ¿cómo se separan?

Tags: html

Tengo en una página varios enlaces seguidos, pero no se respeta el espacio que hay entre ellos. Para una mejor lectura del código primero abro la etiqueta, en la línea de abajo pongo el nombre del enlace y en la línea de abajo cierro la etiqueta. Este ejemplo es muy sencillo, es sólo para visualizar el problema

```html
<a href="">
    EnlaceUno
</a>

<a href="">
    EnlaceDos</a>

<a href="">
    EnlaceTres
</a>
```

El código quiero dejarlo tal como está. Si cierro la etiqueta justo cuando pongo el nombre del enlace, ya no parece que los enlaces estuvieran pegados... pero quiero dejar el código tal como dije al principio, si es posible

Al haber un salto de línea entre el final del nombre del enlace y el cierre de la etiqueta, parece que me lo interpreta y ese espacio forma parte del enlace...

Como veis el EnlaceUno y EnlaceDos están pegados, quiero que se vean separados pero dejando el código tal como digo, ¿se puede hacer?

Gracias

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es poner la etiqueta de cierre justo después del nombre del enlace, pero para una mejor lectura y comprensión del código quiero ponerla debajo, no se cómo se podría dejar debajo y que el espacio entre los enlaces no sea también un enlace

Comment: El código que he puesto está muy simplificado pero básicamente se ve el "problema". Lo único que se me ocurre es ponerlo todo junto en una línea tal que así: <a href="">EnlaceUno</a> y lo mismo con los demás enlaces, pero la dirección del enlace es muy larga y para una mejor comprensión del código quiero separarlo por líneas. ¿Qué quieres que agregue?. Ya te lo estoy diciendo. Ponerlo todo en una línea pero quiero saber si puedo hacerlo en líneas diferentes... Sabes? No me lo quieres decir? Me das una pista? Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con hojas de estilo, agrega: `<style>a{ margin-right:10px }</style>`.

Answer (score 1):

Si los enlaces van a estar uno debajo del otro puedes separarlos con la etiqueta 
 para saltar líneas. Si van a estar de manera horizontal en tu hoja de estilos debes modificar el atributo margin a tus enlaces.

```
a {
margin: 15px;
}
```

los 15 pixeles son a modo de ejemplo.

De esta manera dejas 15 pixeles de margen hacia los 4 lados de tu caja contenedora.
Si solo quieres modificar uno de los margenes puedes usar
margin-top: para el margen superior
margin-right: para el margen derecho
margin-bottom: para el margen inferior
margin-left: para el margen izquierdo

El atributo margin también se puede abreviar así:

margin: valor 1 , valor 2 (donde valor 1 será margin top y bottom y valor 2 serán margin left y right.

o

margin: valor 1, valor 2, valor 3, valor 4

valor1: margin-top

valor 2: margin-right

valor 3: margin-bottom

valor 4: margin-left

Espero te sirva la respuesta, saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas simple es usar un *Espacio sin ruptura*:

```html
<a href="">
    EnlaceUno
</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="">
    EnlaceDos
</a>
&nbsp;
<a href="">
    EnlaceTres
</a>
```